# Preparing JSON data to be stored in a db

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, arrayobject

I need some advice and guidance. As you can see in my sandbox I am fetching (by filtering) covid data for Australia as a JSON object. My intention is to store specific information to a database  (i.e. active, confirmed, deaths, recovered, lastUpdate).

After filtering the JSON object returns and object which has Australia's covid stats as well as an array of objects within it if the country has states.

My specific question is how to handle/store/manipulate/deal with the fetched JSON object prior to writing it to a database? Your guidance/advice/tips are highly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-edison-b62o7?from-embed

=============================================================================

I clearly have a limited understanding with hooks.

I have fetched the data and returned it as an object.  For now I am trying to backup up the active cases data without success.

Where am I totally getting it wrong?

```
  const fetchData = () => {
    const australia = countries
      .filter((aus) => aus.name === "Australia")
      .map((oz) => ({
        active: oz.active,
        confirmed: oz.confirmed,
        deaths: oz.deaths,
        recovered: oz.recovered,
        lastUpdated: oz.lastUpdate
      }));
    setActive(active);
  };
```

I am writing an empty string to the database at the moment.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide samples of the input/expected output of the manipulations and what you've tried or what isn't working to get useful guidance.

Comment: @pilchard  Thank you for your advice... I've added a more code that I'm trying to implement hoping that I can be assisted further.